# t-sql how does this work? SELECT @MyList = ISNULL(@MyList,'') + Title + ', ' FROM Titles

Tags: sql, t-sql, recursion

I came across some very cool t-sql to generate a comma delimited list of column values from selected rows in one t-sql query:

```
SELECT @MyList = ISNULL(@MyList,'')  + Title + ', ' FROM Titles
```

But I can’t figure out how it works.  Somehow it must be doing a recursive call but I don’t know how.
Can anyone explain it to me or send me a link that explains it?
To see it work, use the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE  Titles(
    Title varchar(50)  
    )

    insert Titles  values ( 'Doctor')
    insert Titles   values ( 'Nurse')
    insert Titles   values ( 'Administrator')
    insert Titles   values ( 'CMA')

    select * from Titles

    DECLARE @MyList VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @MyList = ''
    SELECT @MyList = ISNULL(@MyList,'')  + Title + ', ' FROM Titles
    SELECT @MyList
```

Comment: Imagine the database engine iterating through each row of `Titles`. If it executes the `@MyList = ...` assignment for each row, what value will `@MyList` end up with?  There is no recursion here.

Comment: Not really an answer, but may I suggest an alternate method? SELECT STUFF(( SELECT ',' + Title FROM Titles t FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '').  It doesn't require a variable declaration, and thus can be used in a single query.

Comment: You can run into issues with this method especially if you order by the result of a calculation. [The correct behaviour for an aggregate concatenation query is undefined.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment:

```
@MyList = ISNULL(@MyList,'')  + Title + ', '
```

is evaluated for every row of the Titles table. It concatenates each row's `Title` column value to @MyList.

The test `ISNULL(@MyList,'')` is only needed, so that `@MyList` starts with an empty string if it is `NULL`. In your example the `ISNULL` is unnecessary, because @MyList is explicitly set to an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have explained why this builds up your comma delimited list.  You'll notice that you end up with an extra comma at the end, which you can remove afterwards if you wish.  If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) and not have that ending comma:

```
SELECT @MyList = COALESCE(@MyList + ', ','') + Title FROM Titles
```

For the first row, `@MyList` will be `NULL`, so `@MyList + ', '` will evaluate to `NULL` and `COALESCE` will return `''`.  Essentially, processing the first row does this:

`SELECT @MyList = '' + Title`

For subsequent rows, `COALESCE` will return `@MyList + ', '`, and you get the equivalent of

`SELECT @MyList = @MyList + ', ' + Title`.

Comment: COALESCE is not doing anything magical here.  The real difference is that you are appending the comma before the data instead of after.  Using ISNULL in your query would produce identical results.

You also mention that you need SQL2005 or greater.  This is not true.  I know this code works on SQL2000, but it probably works on earlier versions too.

Answer (score 1):

Table `Titles` contains a set of predefined titles, so the query

```
SELECT @MyList = ISNULL(@MyList,'')  + Title + ', ' FROM Titles
```

Does **append** a value of the Title column **for each** row in table `Titles`.

This equivalent to the following loop:

```cs
// Actually  ISNULL(@MyList,'') does initialize 
// @MyList by empty string whilst processing the first row in tsql query
string myList = "";
foreach(string title in Titles)
{
   myList = myList +  ', ' + title;
}
```